# How can I add a random number to each item in foreach loop but to stay the same for 1 day

Tags: php, random, numbers

I'm trying to assign a different random number on each item in a foreach loop but I'd like the number to stay the same for one day.

I've tried simply adding  `<?php echo rand(0,20); ?>` but this obviously just creates a random number per each refresh.

Is there anyway I could keep the same random number per each item for one day without adding it to the database.

for example:

```
item 1 = 2
item 2 = 18
item 3 = 13
item 4 = 6
```

Stays the same for 1 day then changes

Comment: Use `sessions` instead of inserting them into `DB`

Comment: Seed your random number generator using the date before actually generating any random numbers

Comment: I've tried adding sessions but you'd need multiple sessions for each number - I'm not sure how to do this

Comment: Create `array` with your random numbers and then save this `array` with `sessions`

Comment: how would you do this in the loop - sorry bit of a noob!

Comment: I might be wrong, but wouldn't sessions be user specific?

Comment: yeah good point but I'd most likely want them to be different daily

Comment: Can you post how your loop looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like:

```
$not_random_at_all = base_convert(md5($item . date('l jS \of F Y')), 16, 10);
```

Where `$item` is the number of your item (or anything that identifies the item).

It just converts the MD5-Hash of the current date concatenated with your item number to integer.

That means a different random number for every item daily.

Remember that MD5 is not a random number generator and your results might bot be as random as they can be.

Comment: i'm not sure on the downvotes but this seems to be working for me. One thing though - how could i make the random number smaller? I want to do an if statement on the random number but they're pretty huge at the moment

Comment: You could use `crc32` instead of `md5`

Comment: thanks that's certainly smaller - I was thinking two digits preferably

Comment: It would be likely to have multiple items with the same "random" numbe r if you would only use numbers between 1 and 100. It would also not improve the performance of your application at all, if that is your concern.

Comment: If you still want to have smaller numbers, you might want to use the modulus operator (%).

Comment: essentially i have 20 items and I want to call a string based on a random number selection with several if statements. For example if value is between 0-5 say "hello". If value is between 6-20 say "goodbye"

Comment: If you only want numbers between 0..20 then use `$number = $not_random_at_all % 20; `

Comment: but I'd like the number to stay for 24 hours - would that work?

Comment: Yes, `$not_random_at_all = base_convert(md5($item . date('l jS \of F Y')), 16, 10) % 20` will certainly stay the same.

Comment: hmm this is now giving me the same number per each item unfortunately

Comment: Use `$not_random_at_all =  bcmod(base_convert(crc32( date('l jS \of F Y').$i), 16, 10),20);` then.

Comment: This error occurs, because the hash is bigger than the maximum integer value and the built-in modulus operator seems to work only on integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by programming your own random number generator. [This guide shows you how to do it.](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-random-number-generator/)

*Note: Code below from [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-random-number-generator/)*

```
class Random {

    // random seed
    private static $RSeed = 0;

    // set seed
    public static function seed($s = 0) {
        self::$RSeed = abs(intval($s)) % 9999999 + 1;
        self::num();
    }

    // generate random number
    public static function num($min = 0, $max = 9999999) {
        if (self::$RSeed == 0) self::seed(mt_rand());
        self::$RSeed = (self::$RSeed * 125) % 2796203;
        return self::$RSeed % ($max - $min + 1) + $min;
    }

}
```

To call it

```
// set seed
Random::seed(42);

// echo 10 numbers between 1 and 100
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo Random::num(1, 100) . '<br />';
}
```

Now set your seed based on the current date with the [php date function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)

```
// set seed based on date with 
Random::seed(date("z") + 1);
```

This will give you the **same numbers every year**. If you don't want this, use the seed variable of rubo77. With this version you can ensure to get the **same number on different machines** (can't guarantee that with srand).

Comment: Random::seed(date("z Y") + 1) would not give the same result every year.

Answer (score 0):

```
$seed = floor(time()/86400);
srand($seed);
foreach($list as $item){
  echo $item.rand(0,20);
}
```

or to obtain the same value of rand in a determined time interval. 
Another Example: you have an array of 20 elements and you need to obtain a random item every day but not to change in the 24h period (just imagine "Today's Photo" or similar).

```
$seed = floor(time()/86400);
srand($seed);
$item = $examplearray[rand(0,19)];
```

You obtain the same value every time you load the page all the 24h period.

Comment: how would you echo this out?

Comment: That would just create **one** random number, wouldn't it? He want's every item to have a different random number.

Comment: In the loop: `echo $item`

Comment: I added another example